# ajax - save javascript value to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables

After hours of trying to get this to work, i want to ask you :)

So i have a php Page that can display files from a server. Now I can edit
the files with a editor plugin. 
Textarea is the tag where the editor gets rendered. 
To save the changed text from the editor, I have a button that gets the innerHTML from the surrounding pre tag of the text with javascript.
I now want to pass that variable via ajax to a php variable on the site get.php,
so I can save it locally and send it to the server.

The problem is, that there is no reaction at all, if i click the "Save" button. I tested a lot of answers from similar ajax functions here, but none of them gave me a single reaction :/

php main

```
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


...


echo  "<textarea><pre id='textbox'> ";
echo $ssh->exec($display);
echo "</textarea></pre>";

echo '<input type="button" value="Save File" id="butt">';

echo "<script>
var show = document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#butt').click(function() {

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'get.php',
    data: {'variable': show},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
}
});
});
});
</script>";


...
```

get.php

```
if (isset($_POST["variable"])){
$show =$_POST["variable"];
echo $show;
}
```

**Edit:**

This is the actual working state:

```
echo  "<textarea id='textbox'><pre> ";
echo $ssh->exec($display);
echo "</pre></textarea>";

echo '<input type="button" value="Save File" id="butt">';

echo "<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#butt').click(function() {
var show = document.getElementById('textbox').value;

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'get.php',
data: {'variable': show},
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
},
});
});
});
</script>";
```

Comment: Can you confirm in the network tab of your device tools  that the post request is happening at all? If so, with what status code?

Comment: By the way, you are sending the string `'show'` instead of the content of the `show` variable in your post data.

Comment: There is no request event displayed if i click the button.

Comment: "developer tools" that should have been of course, not "device tools". Ok, so the request is not happening at all... Are there any messages in the console that could give any lead maybe? Because the binding looks fine as far as I can see...

Comment: By the way #2: getting the content of the text area should happen inside the click event handler, or you will always get the content of the text area at the start of loading the page (which is probably just empty)

Comment: Thx for #2 i changed it, but it seems that the javascript part cant read the innerHTML of the textbox, thats the reason the ajax part isnt even executed

Comment: Your JS doesn't get innerHTML from the textarea, but from the `pre` tag, because it has the id `textbox`, not the textarea. Why do you need that `pre` element anyway?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest small changes to see if everything is running as it should.

1. - I can see that pre tag is behind textarea closing tag - try to change it
2. - Try putting `var show = document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML;` inside of the ,,butt" function
3. - Then I can see your problem here data: `{'variable': 'show')},` - you are sending 'show' as a string - remove quotes to send it as a variable which will appear as a POST value in PHP site.

Comment: Thx, i did everything, but still not a single reaction. :/ Could it be that ajax doesnt like to be echo´d ?

Comment: Put alert(show) inside of the butt function to display content of the show variable ... it is good for testing ... next thing is - right click on the page ... inspect element - and go to Console Tab - there are events triggered by Javascript on your page - maybe there is some error

Comment: Or `alert("anything")` for that matter, because if the content of the variable is empty, depending on the browser the alert message might not show at all

Comment: The only thing its says is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (   when i display a text file in the editor  at line: data: {(variable: show)},

Comment: ok im running this right now: echo "<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#butt').click(function() {
    var show = document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML;
    alert('anything');

});
});
    </script>";
And it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Change your document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML to document.getElementById('textbox').text .... and btw did you changed textarea and pre closing tags ? /pre should be before /textarea

Comment: Is it possible that the document.getElementByID cant get the content because it is echo´d?

Comment: No why should it? Your JavaScript has no idea and doesn't care whether the markup comes from a static file or was generated by a serverside language... and the error message relatively clearly states what's wrong (your syntax)

Comment: var show = document.getElementById('textbox').text;                                  -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null                                                 Yeah I switched the position of the pre tag.

Comment: This error message also clearly states what's wrong. The element with the id "textbox" can't be found. Please update your original question with the exact markup you currently have after the changes

Comment: put id from PRE to TEXTAREA and change .text to .value

Comment: YAY it finally works, thanks Sir, your a god :), would upvote if i could :P

Comment: Okay getting the content works, i can alert(show); now, but when i add the ajax part, there is still no reaction

Comment: I forgot to add the }, and });

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the `data: {'variable': show)}` part. It should be: `data: {variable: show}`. Also you should use Firebug or Firefox developer tools for these kind of problems. A lot easier to see whats wrong.

Comment: Firebug is no longer being developed and has major issues in the latest Firefox versions. So the default dev tools of whatever browser OP is using should be fine :)

Answer (score -1):

with this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'get.php',
    data: {variable: show)},
    success: function (data){
        alert(data);
```